# Dynamically assigned UIFont does not show immediately in slow simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, refresh, uifont

I have a `UIView` with a `UILabel` for which, I'd like allow the user to dynamically change the font size.  The code below almost works, but the problem is that *after the new `UIFont` is assigned to the label, it doesn't immediately show in the UI.*  Instead, some other UI activity is required to make it show up.

What I'm looking for is a technique where the font change will show up immediately after the gesture is over.

Starting with the technique shown in [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6747815-uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-getting-started), I added a gesture recognizer to the `UIScrollView`.  In the associated `UIViewController`, I implemented `handlePinch(UIpinchGestureRecognizer)`.

Inside that function, I take action only when the gesture begins and ends (no attempt to animate).  If the user indicated zoom, I increase the font by 4 points.  If the user indicated a shrink, I decrease the font by 4 points.  This all works, except for the fact that the screen does not reflect the change until another UI function is executed.  I have only tested this on the simulator, but I presume it would be the same on a real device.

I have tried `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsLayout` and several other odd things on both the `UILabel` as well as the view that was passed to the `handlePinch()` function.

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
  guard let gestureView = gesture.view else {
    return;
  }

  gestureView.transform = gestureView.transform.scaledBy(x: gesture.scale, y: gesture.scale)

  if (gesture.state == UIPinchGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
    pinchD = gestureView.transform.d
    print("pinch started ", pinchD)
  }

  if (gesture.state == UIPinchGestureRecognizer.State.ended) {
    print("pinch ended ", gestureView.transform.d)
    print("compare:", pinchD, gestureView.transform.d)
    let larger = gestureView.transform.d > pinchD
    let fontSize = multiLineLabel.font.pointSize
    if (larger) {
      if (fontSize < 28) {
        let calculatedFont = UIFont(name: multiLineLabel.font.fontName, size: fontSize + 4)
        print("bigger fontSize", fontSize + 4);
        multiLineLabel.font = calculatedFont
      }
    } else {
      if (fontSize > 12) {
        let calculatedFont = UIFont(name: multiLineLabel.font.fontName, size: fontSize - 4)
        print("smaller fontSize", fontSize - 4);
        multiLineLabel.font = calculatedFont
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What needs to be done after the calculatedFont is applied to the `UILabel` to make it show immediately in the app?

ADDITIONAL CLARIFICATION:

`handlePinch()` runs as expected; every time a pinch gesture ends, I see `bigger fontSize...` or `smaller fontSize...` logged.

After the logging, the simulator screen font size remains the same until I do one of several things.  One thing that causes the font size to change is if I swipe to the next item.  Before the animation starts, the font increases.  The font changes also if I hit the back button (the font change shows briefly before the other view appears).

Comment: what do you mean about 'until another UI function is executed'?  
what ui function cause handlePinch would not work anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my presumption was incorrect:

> I have only tested this on the simulator, but I presume it would be the same on a real device.

I believe that was NOT correct.

I'm testing on a very, very old iMac and the simulator is bogged down such that it takes 15 or 30 seconds to update the screen!

So I conclude that the code is working fine after all.

Comment: My beta tester confirmed that it updates instantly on his iPhone device.